# Im not able to build ionic2 app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

im trying to build and ionic 2 app for test im my android but i dont get anything.

My setup (ionic info):

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v5.11.0

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.0.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.36", 
    "typescript": "2.0.3" 
  }
```

The console messages are (ionic build android):

```
Running 'build:before' npm script before build
> ionic-app-base@ build /home/fdom/repos/Pantrify
> ionic-app-scripts build
[15:38:53]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.36 
[15:38:53]  build prod started ... 
[15:38:53]  clean started ... 
[15:38:53]  clean finished in 9 ms 
[15:38:53]  copy started ... 
[15:38:53]  ngc started ... 
[15:38:53]  copy finished in 339 ms 
[15:38:53]  lint started ... 
[15:38:56]  lint finished in 2.52 s 
[15:39:21]  ngc finished in 28.49 s 
[15:39:21]  bundle started ... 
[15:39:35]  bundle finished in 13.74 s 
[15:39:35]  uglifyjs started ... 
[15:39:35]  sass started ... 
[15:39:40]  sass finished in 4.88 s 
[15:39:40]  cleancss started ... 
[15:39:43]  cleancss finished in 3.42 s 
[15:39:52]  uglifyjs finished in 16.86 s 
[15:39:52]  build prod finished in 59.12 s
prompt>_
```

But if a run a ionic serve it goes perfectly:

```
Running 'serve:before' npm script before serve
> ionic-app-base@ watch /home/fdom/repos/Pantrify
> ionic-app-scripts watch
[15:50:20]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.36 
[15:50:20]  watch started ... 
[15:50:20]  build dev started ... 
[15:50:20]  clean started ... 
[15:50:20]  clean finished in 6 ms 
[15:50:20]  copy started ... 
[15:50:20]  transpile started ... 
[15:50:21]  lint started ... 
[15:50:23]  lint finished in 2.46 s 
[15:50:25]  transpile finished in 4.69 s 
[15:50:25]  bundle started ... 
[15:50:25]  copy finished in 4.76 s 
[15:50:36]  bundle finished in 10.69 s 
[15:50:36]  sass started ... 
[15:50:40]  sass finished in 3.84 s 
[15:50:40]  build dev finished in 19.24 s 
[15:50:40]  watch ready in 19.57 s 
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $
```

I tryed a lot, removing/adding platform, uninstaslling/installing node modules, build with another node version using nvm(4.4.0, 5.11.0, 5.6.0) but nothing works. I think its the ionic cli but not sure.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some below command:

```
$ionic platform remove android
$ionic hooks add 
$ionic platform add android
```

Comment: ill try this, maybe this is the solution cause at work i can build perfectly.